# HSTS Preload section on .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite, hsts, mod-headers

Recently having moved a site to SSL, I looked into enforcing HSTS for eventual preload.  The syntax is approved and the Chrome List allows it to be OK.  However, not being a coder at all, a slight problem arises.

I have:

```
php_value upload_tmp_dir "/tmp"

# Force SSL

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Redirect to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [E=HTTPS,R=301,L]

# Security header
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; preload; includeSubdomains" env=HTTPS

# End Force SSL'
```

This seems OK, but some sites on the web --- I won't clutter this with cites   --- advise `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` and others have `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on`

Logically ON seems right, but I need to know what is correct.  Neither give errors.

Answer (score 5):

> ...advise `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` and others have `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on`

That wouldn't make sense in the context given as these are obviously opposites (I would be interested to see the full examples you are quoting this from).

However, maybe you mean `off` vs `!on`? These are equivalent in this context. The `!` prefix negates the regex, so that effectively means *not* "on" (ie. it must be "off").

So, in the context of your directives above, where you are testing whether HTTPS is not active, then the following are equivalent:

```
# Does the HTTPS server variable contain "off"?
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

# Does the HTTPS server variable not contain "on"?
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
```

The HTTPS server variable is either set to "on" or "off". (Or, it's not set at all - but that is dependent on your server/SSL setup and you will have already discovered that by now.)

Which you use is really just a matter of preference.

---

### Other notes on HSTS and `.htaccess`

> ```
> # Redirect to www
> ```

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [E=HTTPS,R=301,L]
```

> ```
> # Security header
> ```

```
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; preload; includeSubdomains" env=HTTPS
```

(I assume the extra `.com` in `^example.com\.com` is just a typo? That should be just `^example\.com`.)

`E=HTTPS` - The purpose of setting the *environment variable* `HTTPS` on the `RewriteRule` *redirect* is to be able to conditionally set the `Strict-Transport-Security` HTTP response header on the canonical (HTTPS only) non-www to www redirect**<sup>[*1]</sup>** (ie. `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`) based on the `env=HTTPS` check on the `Header` directive. However, for this header to be set on the *redirect*, you'll also need to use the `always` keyword on the `Header` directive, like so:

```
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; preload; includeSubdomains" env=HTTPS
```

As noted in the [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#header), regarding the use of `always` with the `Header` directive when setting headers on *redirects*:

> - You're adding a header to a locally generated non-success (non-2xx) response, such as a redirect, in which case only the table corresponding to `always` is used in the ultimate response.

**<sup>[*1]</sup>** This header must be set on the redirect in order to satisfy point 4.1 of the [HSTS preload submission requirements](https://hstspreload.org/#submission-requirements):

> If you are serving an additional redirect from your HTTPS site, that redirect must still have the HSTS header (rather than the page it redirects to).

---

Just an additional comment on the [linked article](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/htaccess-header-set-doesnt-set.613111/) in the comments below, that states:

> The `env=HTTPS` environment variable wasn't working as expected. So I used the `E=HTTPS` flag on the www redirect to **set the `env=HTTPS` environment variable on the next request**.

The last bit about setting "the `env=HTTPS` environment variable on the next request" isn't quite correct. It's setting the `HTTPS` environment variable on the *current (redirect) response*. By the time the "next request" comes about (ie. the browser has responded to the redirect), this environment variable (that was set above) is long forgotten. But this does require the `always` keyword to be used on the `Header` directive (as mentioned above).

---

> ```
> Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; preload; includeSubdomains" env=HTTPS
> ```

Just a minor point, and maybe this doesn't actually matter, but... I would include the `preload` directive at the end of the list of directives. For example:

```
 Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload" env=HTTPS
```

The `preload` directive is not actually part of the [HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797#page-15) specification. It is *only* required by the preload list. Other user-agents/browsers do not use this and may not even understand this, so it would be more logical to put this at the end of the list. Some parses might stop as soon as they reach an "invalid" directive?

---

**UPDATE:** However, this does not appear to be a complete solution. As it stands, the HSTS response header is *only* being set on the non-www to www (HTTPS) redirect. It's not being set on any other HTTPS responses, which it would need to be. It's quite possible that this header is being returned by the application itself, but there is no evidence of that here (except that the OP states that it does pass HSTS validation).

For a more complete `.htaccess`-only solution see [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/131970/1243) to the following related question: [HSTS implementation in .htaccess when using www subdomain](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/115125/hsts-implementation-when-using-www-tld)

Comment: Thank you.  You are correct  off vs !on.        OFF = https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/ssl/forcing-https  ON= https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33268353/using-htaccess-to-redirect-http-http-www-and-https-www-to-https

Comment: Sorry, hitting enter just closes the comment.

Comment: E=HTTPS came from here as far as I remember  ---  I looked at a lot of tedious examples !   ---  https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/htaccess-header-set-doesnt-set.613111/

Comment: @Claverhouse Thanks for the links. Incidentally, `!=on` is effectively the same as `!on` in this context (the result is the same here). However, there is a difference. The `=` prefix makes it an exact string comparison, whereas without `=`, it's a _regex_ and so checks for "on" _anywhere_ inside the _TestString_. It can only ever be "on" or "off", so the result is the same. Very interesting about the use of `E=HTTPS` on the _redirect_ - my initial comment on that was wrong. However, you'll need to add the `always` keyword to the `Header` directive for that to work OK. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Check whether HTTPS ISN'T on

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Check whether HTTPS IS off

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Check whether connection runs NOT on secure https port 443

But all of them do the same: check if no https and redirect to https.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=10886400; includeSubDomains; preload"
</IfModule>
```

You know already what it does.

Comment: The `<IfModule>` wrapper is not required here. In fact, if you are going for the "HSTS preload list" then the wrapper should be removed since this header is _mandatory_. You are also missing the recommended `env=HTTPS` condition.

Comment: `IfModule` wrapper is for check purpose, whether the addressed module is already installed. Regarding `env=HTTPS` i'm not sure - there are a bunch of working examples with and without it.

Comment: "`IfModule` wrapper is for check purpose..." - Yes, but that's the problem. If mod_headers is not installed then the directive simply fails _silently_ and the header is not set. This header _must_ be set for HSTS to be successful. This _should_ break if mod_headers is not available since this header is not optional. See this related question with regards to mod_rewrite (same idea): https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/112600/is-checking-for-mod-write-really-necessary

Comment: Thank you both. The forum now incorporates your suggestions.

Incidentally ( I am not asking for further advice ), on WordPress, the excellent hackrepair section has to go first on .htaccess.

https://hackrepair.com/articles/website-security/how-to-block-bots-from-seeing-your-website-bad-bots-and-drive-by-hacks-explained

Just to note, the preload thing does not seem to like that !

Comment: Added above as comment rather than as before misplaced.  Incidentally to reply, I left the hackrepair in and am not bothering with preloading the WordPress...