# .htaccess - how do i redirect TLDs?

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect, top-level-domains

I'm currently using my .htaccess to force all HTTP requests to HTTPS, and that is working very well. However I would also like to redirect some TLDs. For example -

`http(s)://(www.)example.info` -> `https://example.com` or `https://www.example.com`

`http(s)://(www.)example.net` -> `https://example.com` or `https://www.example.com`

My current `.htaccess` file contains:

```
RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

The incoming requests that I would like to redirect from may or may not be HTTPS, and the "www" may or may not be present.

The other thing I'd like to do, and sorry if this should be in a separate question but I believe that the answers would be related....

Can I wrap the previously described redirects in a conditional that will skip them if the server is `localhost`?

Comment: What is your `RewriteOptions inherit` directive for?

Comment: I believe that it was automatically placed there via cPanel and I left it in and added it to the example in case it had some affect on any answers.

Comment: `RewriteOptions Inherit` "inherits" mod_rewrite directives from a parent config (by literally copying them to the end of your current `.htaccess` file). This could be relevant, particularly since you don't have an `L` flag on your original directives. This directive shouldn't normally be required, especially if you don't actually know what it's doing. However, some _hosts_ might require this.

Comment: I think I might know how it got in to the .htaccess file. Originally the site was hosted under a parent domain/account. Then a new cPanel account was created for it and the files were copied over. In its original location it was located in `~/public_html/example` and `~/public_html` also had an .htaccess file. If I understand you correctly it's likely that `RewriteOptions Inherit` is no longer necessary.

Comment: Yes, `RewriteOptions Inherit` is probably not required anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `http(s)://(www.)example.info` -> `https://example.com` or `https://www.example.com`

On reading your question it doesn't sound like you want to canonicalise the www subdomain? However, you should be. Decide whether it should be `www.example.com` or `example.com` and stick to that. For the rest of this answer, I'll assume `www.example.com` should be the canonical domain.

---

The easiest way would be to say... if the request is not for the canonical domain then redirect to the canonical domain. This will then catch any of the *other* TLDs and whether they are www or not (and even whether they are FQ or not).

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.example.com
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Notes about the above:

- Addition of the `OR` flag on the first condition. So *either* of the first two conditions must be successful (not just both of them).
- The `=` prefix defines a lexicographical *exact* string comparison. ie. not a regex. So no need to escape literal dots or use start/end-of-string anchors.
- Removal of the parentheses on the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. No need to capture anything, since you aren't using it.
- Added the *flags* on the `RewriteRule`. This should ultimately be a 301 permanent redirect, although first testing with a 302 temporary redirect (to avoid caching) is preferable. If you ever add more directives then you will need the `L` flag to stop further processing.
- Add back the two cPanel additions if you wish (required for AUTO-SSL renewal). Or these can be separated into their own rule.

> Can I wrap the previously described redirects in a conditional that will skip them if the server is `localhost`?

There are quite a few ways to block the directives from local development (which can depend on your server config / version). If you simply want to block this single mod_rewrite rule from applying to the Host `localhost` then just add another condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

ie. Only when the `Host` header is *not* "localhost".

---

#### Summary

So, in summary, adding back the cPanel *conditions* (for AUTO-SSL renewal), we have:

```
RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

However, also note the comment by @xsrf if you are planning on implementing [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security).

See also [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/884922/49157) to the following ServerFault question for more information regarding those additional directives (AUTO-SSL renewal) added by cPanel:
https://serverfault.com/questions/884915/apache-htaccess-multiple-rewrite-conditions-for-multiple-rules

Comment: For best practice, you should redirect to https:// first on the same host, then redirect to the preferred host. This is important if you use security features like HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS). Only this way the HSTS setting will be remembered for all domains by the browser.

Comment: @MrWhite Sorry about not replying sooner.  

I've been able to get the `.info` and `.net` to successfully redirect to `.com`. Thank you!  

However I'm not sure if I've added the AUTO-SSL stuff correctly,

Comment: @jxmot_wd You literally just need to copy those two `RewriteCond` directives back to the same place; immediately before the `RewriteRule` directive. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @MrWhite Thank you very much for updating the answer, as it turns out my "guess" was correct. Thanks again for your time and excellent explanations. I'm now aware of things that I didn't before.Like HSTS for example, I did some reading about it and found that it can be enabled by adding `Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" env=HTTPS` to .htaccess. However I'm a bit unclear in regards to its location in the .htaccess file. My guess is that it would be the first line in the file.

Comment: @MrWhite I did follow your advice regarding "www", thank you!

Comment: @jxmot_wd If you have a specific question about HSTS then you can perhaps ask another question, or refer to this related question/answer: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/112263/hsts-preload-section-on-htaccess