# HSTS and redirecting to www. sub domain

Tags: 301-redirect, https, apache2, hsts

I am trying to setup HSTS for my website but running into some problems regarding the response headers and the use of a sub domain. What I would like is for all HTTP traffic to redirect to `https://www.example.co.uk`.

I have been using the information on the following website as a guide: https://www.danielmorell.com/blog/how-to-configure-hsts-on-www-and-other-subdomains.

The examples on the above website show the strict-transport-security (STS) header at all the redirect stages.

E.g. `http://example.com` 301 redirects to `https://example.com` (STS in header). Then `https://example.com` redirects to `https://www.example.com` (STS in header).

However when I try my own domain I only get the STS header on the initial redirect and not the next redirection to the `https://www.` sub domain.

Examples from my own testing:

1. `http://example.co.uk` (301) to `https://example.co.uk` (STS in header) (301) to `https://www.example.co.uk` (No STS in header).
2. `http://www.example.co.uk` (301) to `https://www.example.co.uk` (No STS in header).
3. `https://example.co.uk` (STS in header) then (301) to `https://www.example.co.uk` (No STS in header).
4. `https://www.example.co.uk` (No STS in header).

Below is a copy of the header response using option 1 above:

### `http://example.co.uk`

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Mon, 04 Feb 2019 18:14:30 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: `https://example.co.uk`/
Content-Length: 237
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

### `https://example.co.uk`/

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Mon, 04 Feb 2019 18:14:33 GMT
Server: Apache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31557600; includeSubDomains;
Location: https://www.example.co.uk/
Content-Length: 241
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

### `https://www.example.co.uk/`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 04 Feb 2019 18:14:35 GMT
Server: Apache
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=fkjqaomopnp03uforuptdu3u17; path=/
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

I'm just wondering if my setup is working correctly or should the strict-transport-security header appear in the header response from the `https://www.` sub domain as well.

My website is running on a shared Apache server. I have a valid Le's encrypt cert with `CN = example.co.uk`.

I have tried the suggestions at: [HSTS implementation when using www.TLD](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/115125/hsts-implementation-when-using-www-tld) but it didn't seem to solve my problem.

My .htaccess is shown below:

```
<if "%{HTTPS} == 'on'">
  Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31557600; includeSubDomains;"
</if>

## Base Redirects ##

# Turn on Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect to secure HTTPS before changing host
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{https} off  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

# Remove trailing slash from non-filepath urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.co.uk/%1 [R=301,L]

# Include trailing slash on directory 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://www.example.co.uk/$1/ [R=301,L]

# Force HTTPS and WWW 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{https} off  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This article appears to be a good reference for this question: https://www.sentinelstand.com/article/http-strict-transport-security-hsts-canonical-www-redirects

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks for your reply. I tried the suggestion in the piece about creating a 1px image, requesting it from https:// www.example.co.uk using https:// example.co.uk but it didn't work. The code used was <img src="https:// example.co.uk/a.gif" style="display: none;" />. I also tested one of my sub domains https:// m.example.co.uk and it set the HSTS header. I created 2 more sub domains: https:// test.example.co.uk and https:// a.example.co.uk and both set the HSTS header so the includeSubDomains directive is working. So the issue appears to be with the https:// www. sub domain.

Comment: I've spoken to my host and they can't see any problems their end and have suggested I ask a developer for advice regarding the redirects and HSTS isssue.